# Solve the following equation $y''=y(y')^3$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following equation
$$
{y''=y(y')^3}
$$

---

I tried the method of separation of variables, it didn't work
any solution or hint to solve this equation?
Thank you.

Comment: we see that $$y(x)=C$$ is a solution

Comment: Since that is a badly non-linear equation, you aren't going to be able to give a simple formula for a general solution.  I would be inclined to try a "series solution".  If $y= a_0+ a_1x+ a_2x^2+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ a_nx^n+ \cdot\cdot\cdot$ them $u

Comment: Didn't edit fast enough!  Since that is a badly non-linear equation, you aren't going to be able to give a simple formula for a general solution.  I would be inclined to try a "series solution".  If $y= a_0+ a_1x+ a_2x^2+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ a_nx^n+ \cdot\cdot\cdot$ then $y'= a_1+ 2a_2x+ 3a_3x^2+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ na_nx^{n-1}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot$ and $y''= 2a_2+ 6a_3x+ 12a_4x^2+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot$.  Put those into the differential equation and you will get an equation which you can solve, approximately, by restricting to a finite power.

Comment: @user247327 "you aren't going to be able to give a simple formula": mh, I am not so sure...

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{6y''}{y'^2}=6yy'$$

($6$ introduced to keep integer coefficients), then

$$-\frac6{y'}=3y^2+C.$$

The rest is yours. It is even possible to express $y$ as a function of the independent variable by solving a cubic.

(The comment by Dr. Sonnhard Graubner still holds.)

> $y=\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{C+(C'+3x)^2}-(C'+3x)}+\sqrt[3]{-\sqrt{C+(C'+3x)^2}-(C'+3x)}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT...The equation is equivalent to $$y'\frac{dy'}{dy}=yy'^3$$

Therefore either $y'=0$, leading to the constant solution, or...

Answer (score 0):

Examining the original equation, it looks as if $y$ is a power function. So guessing that $y$ is of the form $x^a$ (where $a$ is constant) gives $(a-1)(a)x^{a-2} = x^aa^3x^{3a-3}$. For both sides to have some power of $x$ then $a-2=4a-3 \Rightarrow a=\frac{1}{3}$. However that yields the incorrect result: $-\frac{2}{9}x^{-\frac{5}{3}}=\frac{1}{27}x^{-\frac{5}{3}}$.

Refining the guess to $y=bx^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and substituting back into original equation gives $b=-\sqrt[3]{6}$, so a solution is $y=-\sqrt[3]{6x}$.

And, indeed, $(-\sqrt[3]{6x})^{\prime\prime} = (-\sqrt[3]{6x})\cdot[(-\sqrt[3]{6x})^\prime]^3$

Answer (score 0):

Let y'=z
y''=dz/dx=(dz/dy)(dy/dx)=z(dz/dx)
z(dz/dy)=y.z.z.z
dz/dy=y.z.z
dz/(z.z)=y.dy
-1/z=(y.y)/2+a
z=-2/(y.y+A)
dy(y.y+A)=-2dx
(y.y.y)/3+A.y+B=-2x
x=-(y.y.y)/6+A.y+B

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/228959) to format your post; in its current form, it's almost unreadable.