# Second Order Nonlinear Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could you help me solve this differential equation?

$$yy''=2(y')^2$$

Comment: Step 1: Post the problem, not a link to the problem.  Step 2: Post a useful title.  Step 3: Post your own efforts toward solving the problem.  Step 4: Profit.

Comment: divide through by $y'y$

Comment: I think the left side is $yy''$, not $yy'$.

Comment: Yeah, my typo. Tx

Comment: Not a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304269/solve-the-following-equation-y-yy3#2304284

Answer (score 1):

Hint: note that
$$0 = 2(y')^2-yy'' = y^3\left( \frac 1 y \right)''$$

Comment: ok, but how might op see this on his or her own?

Answer (score 1):

Hint...use $y''=y'\frac{dy'}{dy}$ so that you have either $y'=0$ or a separable variable differential equation...

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Rewrite equation as: $$\tfrac{y{y}''-({y}')^2}{y^2} = \tfrac{({y}')^2}{y^2}$$
Then if we substitute $\omega (x)=\tfrac{{y}'}{y}$ our equation will be in the form: $${\omega}'(x)=\omega ^2(x)$$.

Answer (score 0):

$yy'' = 2(y')^2$
divide through by $yy'$

$\frac {y''}{y'} = 2\frac {y'}{y}\\
\ln y' = 2\ln y + C\\
y' = Cy^2$

Can you solve that diff eq?

Continued....

$\frac {C y'}{y^2} = 1$

Remeber that C is arbitrary, so there is no need to keep track of its sigh, and I can replace $C$ with $\frac 1C$ if it suits me.

$\frac {C }{y} = t + D\\
 y = \frac {C}{t + D}$

Shall we check?  (Now we will need to keep track of signs)

$y' = -\frac {C}{(t + D)^2}\\
y'' = 2\frac {C}{(t + D)^3}\\
yy'' = 2\frac {C^2}{(t + D)^3} = 2(y')^2$